# Implement an Autocomplete Component in React-Typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-typescript

> I am new in React-Typescript. I want to create autocomplete textbox in my project using react typescript. I search in google i got some sample code. I try use in my application. I got some error.

In my Autocomplete.tsx i got the some error my error i will explain below and when i bind the autocomplete component in index.tsx i got the error in data.

AutoComplete.tsx

```
import react, { ChangeEvent, FC, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { FaArrowDown } from "@react-icons/all-files/fa/FaArrowDown";

import {
    AutoCompleteContainer,
    AutoCompleteIcon,
    Input,
    AutoCompleteItem,
    AutoCompleteItemButton
} from "./styles";
const Root = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
`;

interface IData {
    name: string;
    code: string;
}
interface autoCompleteProps {
    iconColor?: string;
    inputStyle?: react.CSSProperties;
    optionsStyle?: react.CSSProperties;

    data: any[];
}
export const AutoComplete: FC<autoCompleteProps> = ({
    iconColor,
    inputStyle,
    optionsStyle,
    data
}) => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState({
    text: "",
    suggestions: []
    });
    const [isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible] = useState(true);
    const onTextChanged = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    let suggestions = [];
    if (value.length > 0) {
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, "i");
        suggestions = data.sort().filter((v: IData) => regex.test(v.name));
    }
    setIsComponentVisible(true);
    setSearch({ suggestions, text: value });
    };

    const suggestionSelected = (value: IData) => {
    setIsComponentVisible(false);

    setSearch({
        text: value.name,
        suggestions: []
    });
    };

    const { suggestions } = search;

    return (
    <Root>
        <div
        onClick={() => setIsComponentVisible(false)}
        style={{
            display: isComponentVisible ? "block" : "none",
            width: "200vw",
            height: "200vh",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            position: "fixed",
            zIndex: 0,
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }}
        />
        <div>
        <Input
            id="input"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={search.text}
            onChange={onTextChanged}
            type={"text"}
            style={inputStyle}
        />
        <AutoCompleteIcon color={iconColor} isOpen={isComponentVisible}>
            <FaArrowDown />
        </AutoCompleteIcon>
        </div>
        {suggestions.length > 0 && isComponentVisible && (
        <AutoCompleteContainer style={optionsStyle}>
            {suggestions.map((item: IData) => (
            <AutoCompleteItem key={item.code}>
                <AutoCompleteItemButton
                key={item.code}
                onClick={() => suggestionSelected(item)}
                >
                {item.name}
                </AutoCompleteItemButton>
            </AutoCompleteItem>
            ))}
        </AutoCompleteContainer>
        )}
    </Root>
    );
};
```

Index.tsx

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { AutoComplete } from "./AutoComplete";
import data from "./data.json";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
    <>
    <h2>Simple-React Autocomplete Functional-component Tsx</h2>

    <AutoComplete
        inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: "PaleTurquoise" }}
        optionsStyle={{ backgroundColor: "LemonChiffon" }}
        data={data}
        iconColor="Turquoise"
    />
    </>,
    rootElement
);
```

Data.json

```
[
    { "name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF" },
    { "name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX" },
    { "name": "Albania", "code": "AL" },
    { "name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ" },
    { "name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS" },
    { "name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD" },
    { "name": "Angola", "code": "AO" },
    { "name": "Anguilla", "code": "AI" }
]
```

> In index.ts file i got the error when i bind the data={data} value
> (JSX attribute) autoCompleteProps.data: any[]

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2740)
```

```
AutoComplete.tsx(27, 3): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & autoCompleteProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

> Autocomplete.tsx file (How to resolve the issue)

In suggestions line error:(property) suggestions: never[]

```
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try changing this

```
interface autoCompleteProps {
    iconColor?: string;
    inputStyle?: react.CSSProperties;
    optionsStyle?: react.CSSProperties;

    data: IData[];
}
```

and this

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState({
    text: "",
    suggestions: [] as IData[]
    });
```

and also this

```
let suggestions : IData[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

import data from "./data.json";

Your file name is Data.json
and you don't have an argument name data.
I clearly can't see how you did this but make sure your data that you are getting is an array and not an object that has an array inside it